# Consolidate Multiple Workbooks Into One

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to consolidate data from multiple workbooks into one Master workbook. All workbooks, including the master workbook, have the same worksheets. The data in the worksheets, however, is different. Each workbook is created from asking the same survey questions. I am looking to consolidate all survey answers into one workbook.

Code:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim lastRowNumber As Double
Dim lastColumnNumber As Double
Dim theLastCell As String
Dim copyRange  As Range
Dim pasteRange As Range
Dim sheetName As String
Dim copyRangeString As String
Dim pasteRangeString As String

   Do While myFile <> ""
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=myPath & myFile)
      DoEvents
      wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A2:D2").Interior.color = RGB(51, 98, 174)




For i = 1 To 8
    lastRowNumber = lastRowUsed(wb.Sheets(i))
    lastColumnNumber = wb.Sheets(i).Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    theLastCell = Cells(lastRowNumber, lastColumnNumber).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
    Set copyRange = wb.Worksheets(i).Range("A2:" & theLastCell)
    copyRangeString = "A2:" & theLastCell
    lastRowNumber = lastRowUsed(theWorkbook.Sheets(i)) + lastRowUsed(wb.Sheets(i))
    pasteRangeString = "A" & lastRowNumber & ":" & theLastCell
    theWorkbook.Sheets(i).Range(pasteRangeString) = wb.Sheets(i).Range(copyRangeString).value
    copyRangeString = ""
    pasteRangeString = ""
    sheetName = wb.Sheets(i).name
    MsgBox sheetName

Next

  wb.Close
  DoEvents
  myFile = dir
   Loop
```

I am trying to accomplish this by looping through each Excel file in a folder, looping through (1-8) of the worksheets. Creating a range of the data in each worksheet, and then copying and pasting into the `theWorkbook` "master" workbook. For whatever reason, only data from the last workbook in the folder is getting copied.

Any and all help is much appreciated!

Comment: `theLastCell = ...`. What kind of variable is that? I assume you want to `Dim theLastCell as Range`, then do `Set theLastCell = wb.sheets(i).Cells(...)`.  Currently, the unqualified `Cells()` will return the information from whatever the *ActiveSheet* is, which is not necessarily the sheet you want.

Comment: @BruceWayne Edited code with "Dims"

Comment: You're using a lot of `String`, where `Range` would be preferable.  I suggest going through this and updating those to `Range`, and use accordingly. And again, make sure you qualify all range objects with the worksheet you expect them to be on.

Comment: @brucewayne Updated the code and still having same issue. One instance of this is there are two excel folders. In Sheet 8, there is one row of responses in each file. However, in the consolidated sheet, there are 4 rows of the response in the second file.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this code? I don't think it will ever go into your `Do While..` loop as in the first instance, `myFile` will have no value so how would it ever go into the loop? Infect none of your variables are assigned a value before you enter the loop